# You have gotten: Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysqli

I tried this to make it work and one of my friends gave me this and he couldn't figure out why it won't work and gives this error here is the code

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT clicks FROM affiliate WHERE ID ='$ID'");
$stmt->bind_param("i", "$conn");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($clicks); // Store the result in the $clicks variable

$clicks++; // Increment clicks
echo "$clicks";
```

I get the following error:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Comment: `$stmt->bind_param("i", "$conn");` `$conn`? Why?

Comment: in addition of @u_mulder this line is useless, since you have no wildcard in your query for binding a param: please check the documentation: http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: And what are you trying to bind, you have no placeholders.

Comment: @u_mulder it was the id of something would u like the entire pages code?

Comment: Id of something is `$ID`, `$conn` is a database connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper code:

```
// Add `?` as a placeholder
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT clicks FROM affiliate WHERE ID = ?");
// Bind $ID value to this `?` placeholder
$stmt->bind_param("i", $ID);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($clicks); // Store the result in the $clicks variable

$stmt->fetch();   // fetch result to fill `$clicks` with actual value

$clicks++; // Increment clicks
echo "$clicks";
```

Comment: why does it add on one more click than whats in the database @u_mulder

Comment: Do you see line `$clicks++;`? There's even a comment what it does. Do you understand what comment says?

Comment: `++` means  `increment value by 1`.

Comment: so if i get rid of the ++ it will do it from 0?

Comment: Why you ask? Try and see the results.